# logic in prolog language

Tags: prolog

I have a question in prolog here is the code:

```
sound(time1).
sound(time2).

sun(time3).

relax(X):-
    not(sound(X)),
    !,
    sun(X).
relax(_):-
    sun(_).
```

now I an running - `relax(T)`. I get true when I run `relax(F)` I get true also. Why does it happen?

and one more question, why `relax(time4)`. also gets false? I think I am missing something.
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `relax(T)` and `relax(F)` both give the same result, is normal: uppercase identifiers are **variables**. So the **two queries are semantically the same**: you query with an ungrounded variable.

Now why do we get `true.`? If you query `relax(T)`, Prolog will first call the first clause of `relax(X)`.

The first clause has a body that starts with `not(sound(X))`. So we actually query `not(sound(T))`. Not is satisfied by the *negation as finite failure* principle: Prolog will aim to "prove" `sound(T)`, and if that fails (it cannot find a way to satisfy that query).

So now Prolog queries `sound(T)`, and **this query is satisfied**: indeed, `sound(time1)` satisfies this query, since Prolog reasons that now `T = time1`. As a result `not(sound(T))` is `false`, and thus Prolog backtracks.

Now Prolog will try the next clause: `relax(_) :- sun(_).` The `_` is a "wildcard" or "don't care" variable. Furthermore if you use multiple `_`s in the same clause, those are *not* related. So you basically say: everything is `relax/1`, given there is at least one `sun/1`. So now Prolog will query for a `sun(_)`. This query succeeds: `sun(time3)` is a valid candidate, since `_ = time3`. So that means that `relax(_)` succeeds. We did not alter the variable `T` (or `F`), so Prolog can only say that the query is `true`.

Now if we query `relax(time4)`, that's a different story. Again Prolog will first try to satisfy the first clause of `relax/1`. This is again done by calling `not(sound(time4))`. But note that **`time4` is a constant**. And in Prolog **all constants are different**: so `time1` and `time4` cannot unify.

So now Prolog first aims to unify `sound(time1)` (first clause for `sound/1`) with `sound(time4)`, but since `time1` and `time4` are different, that fails. Next it aims to unify `sound(time2)` (second clause of `sound/1`) with `sound(time4)`, but again no luck. Now there are no clauses of `sound/1` anymore. So Prolog gives up and considers `not(sound(time4))` to be true.

That means that Prolog will continu in the body of the first clause of `relax/1`. The next statement is a `!`, that is a "*cut*" in Prolog. It means that Prolog should, for this branching point - no longer consider the remaining clauses. So it will from now on, ignore the second clause of `relax/1`. Next it encounters `sun(X)`. So now Prolog will call `sun(time4)` and aim to satisfy this. It will aim to unify with the first (and only) clause of `sun/1`: `sun(time3)`. But as said before, `time3` and `time4` do not unify. So as a result, that fails. Since Prolog cannot take the second clause of `relax/1` (due to the cut (`!`)), it thus has exhausted all the options, and decides that the query `relax(time4)` is `false`.

Comment: wow thank you so much!
one more small question. if the cut was at the end of the sentence like this: relax(X):-
    not(sound(X)), sun(X),!.
the answer about time4 is the same? I mine what is the point of putting the cut sign in the middle there?I would think that after we get  true in not(sound(X)) we will stop and send true. hope  you understand me